# To say "It will mean a lot to me": "много значить" vs "многоe значить"

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Спасибо. Для меня это будет **много** значить.
>
> Спасибо. Для меня это будет **многое** значить.

I wonder how the adverb "много" and the pronoun "многое" differ in meaning and usage in this specific instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is about importance:

> Для меня это будет **много** значить. -> It will mean much (a lot) to me.

The second one is about variety of (countable) meanings which might follow:

> Для меня это будет **многое** значить. -> It will mean many things to me.

Comment: In some cases, indeed, there is a connotation of "multiple benefits" when using "многое".  But sometimes it's used just like the first form. For example, ["Эта сумма для меня многое значит…", Леонид Утёсов](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE%E5%20%E7%ED%E0%F7%E8%F2&p=1&docid=49054&sid=1503)

Comment: I agree that the version with **многое** is less definite and can mean both. In some context it can even mean something opposite to 'benefits', like several _negative_ conclusions from the information (not emotion as in case of _много_).

Answer (score 3):

The corpus of Russian language has examples of both phrases in present tense.

> Для меня это **много** значит. [Examples](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE%20%E7%ED%E0%F7%E8%F2&p=0)
>
> Для меня это **многое** значит. [Examples](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EC%ED%EE%E3%EE%E5%20%E7%ED%E0%F7%E8%F2&p=0)

I don't perceive any difference in the meaning. The second form is used considerably less often.

In the future tense I would only use the first form. The second form sounds awkward to me.

Comment: I agree. I would also use only "много".